# Does a 2001 Buick Century have a timing belt or chain?

Tags: buick, century, timing-set

I am trying to find out if a Buick Century 2001 has a timing belt or timing chain?

Answer (score 1):

Per availible parts on [Rockauto](https://www.rockauto.com/en/catalog/buick,2001,century,3.1l+v6,1377086,engine,timing+chain,5724) it appears to have a timing chain.